# Node.js Express Middleware order

Tags: json, node.js, csv, express, middleware

I'm very new to nodejs. I wrote my own middleware function to change incoming csv String to a JSON String.

The middleware stack looks like this:

```
app.use(bodyparser.text());
app.use(csvmiddleware);

app.use('/api',router);
```

The csvmiddleware function just changes the content of req.body and calls next(). the csvmiddleware function shows that req.body contains a JSON String. Then I call `router.route('/r').put(putobj)` and the putobj function outputs the CSV String. the putobj output also appears before the csvmiddleware output in the console. What is wrong with my order? I want the JSON String in my putobj function so I can save it to MongoDB. Thanks for help

Comment: Express evaluates all requests through middleware based on where the middleware is attached then top down. All middleware on the Express server itself and declared before any routes are run for all routes. Without knowing the contents of `router` in the above code or seeing any of the surrounding code its hard to say for sure why its not being evaluated however, based on what you've provided, `csvmiddleware` should be called before any routes inside of `router`.

Comment: I've added the 2 files to pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/CWgfhLY2
https://pastebin.com/fZJUEnx7
didn't want to spam the code here.

Comment: problem is apparently in the csvmiddleware function, if I write `req.body="hello world"` directly before I call `next()` it does change req.body

Comment: I have written an article on importance of middleware order in Express application .Here is the link to the article: https://www.nodexplained.com/blog-detail/2018/01/11/importance-of-middleware-order-in-expressjs-application